# How can I change the order of rows for a multiindex dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to get from the first dataframe to the second? How can I do this?
Can`t change the dataframe structure upfront.

[image]

[image]

Dummy Code:

```
index1 = [("x","1"), ("x","3"), ("x","5"), ("y","1"), ("y","3")]
data = pd.DataFrame(index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(index1), columns = ["A","B"])
data.loc[("x","sum"),:] = [19,10]

index2 = [("x","1"), ("x","3"), ("x","5"), ("x","sum"), ("y","1"), ("y","3")]
data2 = pd.DataFrame(index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(index2), columns = ["A","B"])
```

Comment: Do you mean `sort_index`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `sort_index` by `level=0`:

```
data.sort_index(level=0)

         A    B
x 1    NaN  NaN
  3    NaN  NaN
  5    NaN  NaN
  sum   19   10
y 1    NaN  NaN
  3    NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Thanks, but what can I do that my order remains the same for level 0 ?

Comment: @ManuelK you need to apply a categorical index with custom ordering.

Comment: @ManuelK did you forget to assign it back to `data`? `data = data.sort_index(level=0)`

Comment: @ManuelK Or sort in place: `data.sort_index(level=0, inplace=True)`